# AJAX Call issues - no data passing (relatively inexperienced here!)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I assume i am doing something really simply wrong here (to all you seasoned programmers), but forgive me i have spent hours and hours reading trying to understand how AJAX calls work...

My variables aren't making it to recordsale.php to be inserted into SQL table.

The javascript variables are displayed on the HTML page, so i know they contain data.

Can anyone offer some advice?

(any response knocking my ability will not be appreciated - I AM TRYING :) )

My form submit button in html looks like this

```
<form action="recordsale.php" method="post">
     <input type="image" src="assets/CompleteSale.png" alt="Submit"> </form>
```

My AJAX Post Function:

```
 $( "#submit" ).submit(function( event ) {
alert("hello");
            // Jquery code for making AJAX call to server side script
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "recordsale.php", 
                data: { adultqty: adultticketqty, concessionqty: concessionticketqty, studentqty: studentticketqty, childqty: childticketqty, programqty: programqty, totalsell: totalsaleprice }
            })
           //alert(adultqty + childqty)
        });
```

Recordsale.php

```
<?php 

$adultticketqty = $_POST['adultqty']; 
$concessionticketqty = $_POST['concessionqty']; 
$studentticketqty = $_POST['studentqty']; 
$childticketqty = $_POST['childqty']; 
$programqty = $_POST['programqty']; 
$totalsaleprice = $_POST['totalsell']; 

//include('phpsqlget.php'); 

/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */ 

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "speedway", "speedwayticketsales"); 
// Check connection 
if($link === false){ die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error()); } // Attempt insert query execution 
$sql = "INSERT INTO stdsalesrecords (qtyadulttickets, qtyconcessiontickets, qtystudenttickets, qtychildtickets, qtyprograms, totalsell) VALUES ($adultticketqty,$concessionticketqty,$studentticketqty,$childticketqty,$programqty,$totalsaleprice)"; 

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){ 
    echo "Records inserted successfully."; } 
else{ echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " 

    . mysqli_error($link); } // Close connection mysqli_close($link); 


?>
```

Comment: The params in the ajax call don't look to be set. What is the value of adultticketqty ? Also read about MySQL injection and input validation..

Comment: And you should never post database credentials on the internet

Comment: The values of ticketqtys etc are those from the page (which vary depending on what the user selects)

What portion doesn’t look right to you?

Also the server credentials don’t matter too much, it is a local server and in test mode.  All of these will
Change when it goes live (although it will still not be connected to the net).

Comment: Where are the variables read to be posted? Probably, you have forgotten to share that part of your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i usually do my ajax submissions. there are other ways of handling form submission.
Check out `$(form).serialize()` amongst others.

```
 $( "#submit" ).submit(function( event ) {
   var adultticketcty = $('selector').val();
   //continue filling out the fields and mirror them in the below dataString.

    var dataString = 'adultqty='+adultticketcty+'&concessionqty='+concessionticketqty;

  //Check if you set the correct values in the datastring.
   console.log(dataString);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "recordsale.php", 
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data){
                  //check whatever is returned from recordsale.php
                  console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

then in your recordsale.php do this to see if anything is returned in your ajax success call:

```
$adultticketqty = $_POST['adultqty']; 
$concessionticketqty = $_POST['concessionqty'];
echo $adultticketqty;
```

Not related to the question, but i wanna recommend checking out pdo queries to prevent sql injections etc.

Comment: thanks, i have looked and played with the above method.  The thing that is confusing me is in my form i only have the submit button (or image in this case), the variables which i want to pass through are defined elsewhere on the page.                                                        This line is confusing me, what does the Selector part refer to?   var adultticketcty = $('selector').val();                                                                        I also wonder if my Form layout is correct and the function is actually being called?

Comment: I need to change the SQL injection to PDO, i have used PDO to read from my database on this page so its next on the list, appreciate your advice!

Comment: selector is the general term used to describe the element you want to interact with. so in the case of class="myclass" the selector would be $('.myclass'). From there you can get the value of every parameter available for that element.  by the looks of things, your form is not being triggered. if the stated html is correct, your form lacks an id. $('#formid') should be used.. also - your submit button is an input image.. try starting with just a basic form. add names to your inputs and ids to your form.

Answer (score 0):

solved my issue

had to write a function to write my JS Variables into hidden elements in the form

function save()

```
document.getElementById("qty").value = Aqty;
```

then add the hidden elements to my form

```
<form method="post" name="submit" id="submit" action="record.php" >
<input type="hidden" id="qty" name="qty" value="" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="save();">
```

works a treat!